# Create a rectangle with mousedown event in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to create a rectangle shape using KineticJS with mousedown and drag events but not having much luck with it. Has anyone done anything similar?

Comment: Do you have a snippet of the code that isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/AYHSM/6/

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 600,
    height: 400
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
layer.add(new Kinetic.Rect({
    x:0,
    y:0,
    width:600,
    height:400
}));  // this rect will allow us to use mouse events on the layer. There's probably a better way to do this, but I don't know it.
stage.add(layer);
var rect, down = false; // down is a flag to know whether or not the mouse button is down so that we only resize the new rect when it is down.

layer.on("mousedown", function(e) {

    down = true;
    var r = Math.round(Math.random()*255),
        g = Math.round(Math.random()*255),
        b = Math.round(Math.random()*255);
    rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: e.layerX,
        y: e.layerY,
        width: 11,
        height: 1,
        fill: 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4
    });
    layer.add(rect);
});

layer.on("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (!down) return;

    var p = rect.attrs;

    rect.setWidth(e.layerX - p.x);
    rect.setHeight(e.layerY - p.y);
    layer.draw();
});

layer.on("mouseup", function(e) {
    down = false;
});​
```

Comment: And here I've added the standard photoshop alt/shift/space functionality while dragging: http://jsfiddle.net/AYHSM/3/

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed layer.draw() line completely just setting the width and the height. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, While testing this in different browsers, I noticed that the above code does not work in Firefox 17.0.1. Works fine in IE9 and Chrome. Appreciate if you could check what the issue is. Thanks - Terry

Comment: It looks like FF doesn't define the x and y properties on the event object. use layerX and layerY instead.

Comment: Im thinking of learning KineticJS, so playing with stuff I see in SO (always a good place to learn stuff) and a couple things bugged me about your example.  Main thing, try clicking without moving the mouse, then click somewhere else without moving the mouse, then click and drag and see what you get when you let go of the mouse.  So I changed it a little ... http://jsfiddle.net/AYHSM/7/