# Detecting a Click on Stage but not on Shape in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, kineticjs

In KineticJS, how do you detect a `Click` event where the click occurs outside an object/shape?

I am trying to get a `Rect` to change its scale to `2` when a user clicks on it, and return back to a scale of `1` when the user clicks anywhere outside it.

**JSfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/ABTAD/8/

Managed to detect a click on stage, but clicking on the `Rect` also fires the click handler!!! And somehow the `.setScale(1)` does not do anything, while `console.log` printes something out. How can I prevent the click handler from firing when the click is made on the `Rect` instead of the empty stage?

**JS Code to detect click on stage**

```
window.stage.getContainer().addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    $.each(window.layer.get('.box'), function(index, box) {
       box.setScale(1);
       console.log('clicked on stage');
    });
});
```

Comment: You know Im still learning Kinetic, but heres a JS pointer.  You dont need to put window before things to make them global.  If you put var before a variable decleration then it will be only available in the scope/function it was created in.  Not putting the var before the variable decleration will make it global (the same as putting window. before it).  Did you see this post?.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866660/create-a-rectangle-with-mousedown-event-in-kineticjs he put a rect as the first layer that you can then check against.  Also, is it a good idea to use normal events?

Comment: Thanks!! I actually namespaced them with like `var App = {}; App.stage = ...` Havent seen that post, sounds like a gd idea

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ABTAD/11/

Comment: Awesome, you've nailed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can access the stage content wrapper with stage.getContent().  From there, you can add an event handler like this:

stage.getContent().addEventListener('click', ...); // regular javascript

or

$(stage.getContent()).on('click', ...); // jquery

Comment: From KineticJS 4.3.1 getDOM() is renamed to getContent()

Comment: Hi, can this be done on layers, without having to set a background rect and bind the click event on it?