# how to find out click event in canvas,kinetic js

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I am trying to find click event on shape. when i click on shape like rectangle its become drag-gable but when i click outside of it,it should off its resizable feature.
i tried with blur function but doesn't work. i don't want it on mouse out.
problem is when i click on rectangle it gives me alert but when i click on canvas it gives me that alert twice because that shape is part of canvas.
so please suggest me how to distinguish between click on shape and out side of shape.
how to find out click event in canvas,kinetic js

Comment: Are you using KineticJS events (not DOM events)?  You can have KineticJS listen for clicks on a rectangle like this:  myRect.on("click",function(){ console.log("clicked"); });

Comment: yes,I am using KineticJS events in same ways as u suggested. But click on myRect gives me event on rect but when i click on canvas it should loose its focus or resizable feature which is not happening. means suggest me a way like when i click on Rectangle it will alert "clicked on Rectangle" and when i will click on canvas it will alert "click on canvas". in this scenario you will get both rectangle and canvas alert on click on myRect which i don't want. in short still i am not able to differential canvas click and shape click event. Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you using to listen to click event on the canvas ? Please take a look at this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902747/detecting-a-click-on-stage-but-not-on-shape-in-kineticjs

Comment: I was using box.on('click',function(){alert("box clicked")}); and   canvas.addEventListener('click',function(e){alert("canvas clicked")});   and after that i tried above all solutions but same issue i am getting. when i click on rectangle that rectangle becomes resizable but when i click on canvas it should loose its resizable feature. But here on click of canvas also my box still able to resize which i don't want

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
 appendEvents: function(box, area){
        _self = this;

        // add cursor styling
        box.on('mouseover', function() {
            _self.draw = false;
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        });
        box.on('mouseout', function() {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        });
        box.on('click', function() {
            _self.draw = true;
            _self.focusArea(area, box,box.attrs.x,box.attrs.y);
            _self.openFocusArea(area,box,box.attrs.x,box.attrs.y);
        });
        box.on('dragend', function() {
            _self.draw = false;
            _self.dragArea(area, box);
        });
    },
```

Comment: Create a stage first with `this.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({})` and create layer and box  with `var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();` add them with following code `layer.add(box); this.stage.add(layer);` and underneath directly define events like this and write your onclick code inside this function or make extra functions like i have mentioned